# About drawing and making robots

Tags: halal-haram, drawing

as-salamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh

Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him), who said, “I heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: ‘Whoever makes an image in this world will be told to breathe the soul into it on the Day of Resurrection, and he will never be able to do that.’” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari and Muslim). He [Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him)] also narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Every image-maker will be in the Fire, and every image that he made will be made to appear to him and will torment him in Hell.” Ibn ‘Abbaas said: “If you must do that, then make trees and things that have no soul.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari and Muslim).

I know that drawing living beings is not halal. But I do not know if the point is about *similarity* or *intention*.
(I am developing games so as you know most of the video games includes living beings like human, animal, etc. so I needed a detailed explanation)

**Abbaas said: “If you must do that, then make trees and things that have no soul"**

So I really stuck in here and I wonder if I can draw living beings that is not similar to its real form (like a(n) body/arm/leg is not looking like a real one or drawing a robot or a 3d model of that) or the things that doesn't even have a real form in the world (I am asking the last part depending on this: if there is no living being as so in the world, because there is no living being like that then it cannot have a soul indeed).
Or, is it still not halal because we are still drawing a living being (even if it is not looking like or even it actually is not existing) ?

It can also be considered for making robots or 3d models of them.

Robots are resembling humans in appearance because they may have arms, legs etc. But they are still not the exact same. Even they have legs their legs is not looking like a real skin. They are only made of cables etc. And it means that they have no soul actually. So I want to ask the same question for making robots or their 3d models or their drawings. Is it haram because it is resembling or is halal because it has no soul indeed?

As a second question, is it halal to draw if the character I draw is fully dressed even his hands are covered with a glove or something so nothing can be seen?

I am not drawing any living being for a long time since I made sure that it is not halal. So if it is halal, I will continue by drawing living things that is not looking like its original form or by drawing things that are not actually existing (like aliens, monsters etc.). If not I'll continue not to draw.

Don't get me wrong I am not trying to find an excuse to draw. Just trying to understand clearly. So please tell me if it is not halal. I need it.

I hope I could explain the point I am confused.

Thanks a lot

as-salamu alaikum

Comment: It seems this area is not fully researched by Islamic scholars. You can take picture for id card but you cant draw it, why? Making drawing or 3D models is wrong but making toys for children is ok, why?

Answer (score 1):

Drawing or making animation is haram if you make drawings that have full features of a human or any animals.
Refer to this Fatwa: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/351178/ruling-on-3d-animations-in-video-games

If you want to draw or make games with things which have souls you have to program them without full facial details. Otherwise you will be punished for making images.
Refer to this Fatwa: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/72915/ruling-on-drawing-animate-beings-without-showing-the-facial-features

If you make robots that imitate Allah’s creations which has soul it will be haram too. If you make robots without eyes mouth or like human arms or legs in my opinion it won’t be haram. Because in this case you are  not imitating Allah’s creation.

I am not sure about your second question about making drawings covering full body. I think if you separate the head  and the body it won’t be haram. Because I have seen a Islamic education channel which uses animation that have separated head and body.
If I do mistakes correct me!!

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at that fatwas. And for the last one, drawing a body seperated, I always see Islamic pages or videos or whatever, using drawings like you do. But a hodja in my country does not hesitate to say if something is haram and as he says even we draw things seperated "it won't save you from its punishment anyways". So I am getting away from drawing even it is seperated or not.